# Need help compiling C++ Python project from Github for Conda environment

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'd be really saved if someone could help me on this!

I've been working with an old open source C++ project from github that has not had an official update since Python 3.4: https://github.com/Mindwerks/plate-tectonics

Using a fresh install of Python 3.10.11 I've been able to compile this project in a PyCharm venv using the included setup.py file from this folder: https://github.com/Mindwerks/plate-tectonics/blob/master/pybindings/setup.py

When I compile this, I am able to manually copy+paste the resulting *.pyd file into Pycharm's venv\Lib\site-packages folder. This package runs exactly as it should.

However, for practical reasons, I want to switch to using a conda environment. I've created this environment (python 3.10.13, possibly Cython?) and followed the same steps that worked for PyCharm: open the environment in the conda terminal, run "python setup.py build" and copy the *.pyd file it compiles into the environment's \Lib\site-packages folder.

However, now if I try and run functions from the package, python immediately crashes.

I am completely stumped on what could be the problem and how to resolve it. I don't have much experience with C++ or compiling packages, and I don't get any error messages suggesting what I might be doing wrong. I am assuming conda environments have a different behavior from Pycharm venv's, but I have been unable to find any suggestion as to what I should be doing differently.

If anyone has experience with this and knows what I can do, you'd be a huge help!!!

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is a library of Questions and answers, and to make sure the question is useful in the future, everything necessary to understand the question MUST be in the question. You can't count on links because they get blocked, they rot, and the contents at the page can change. This put you in a bit of a bind because there is probably WAY too much content at those links to put in a Stack Overflow question. Normally the recommendation is to summarize, but that's hard to do with code. For code, you want an [mre].

Comment: Hi user4581301. Thank you. I understand the problem, but as you recognize, I am in a bind. My main problem is that I lack the understanding of c++ to Python compiling to even know what someone would need to begin to diagnose the problem. At this point, I would be happy just with a response that enables me to ask a better question.

Comment: these are a few things missing from your question
1. detailed steps with exact commands to replicate the problem - so something like - Part 1 - create python env with version 3.11.x - a. run `pip install ...`, b. run `git pull ...` c. run `gcc ...`, `cp ...*.pyd ...*.pyd` etc. and the expected output vs the obtained output
2. since you're compiling a binary - the os and cpu architecture and any other details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was in the following chunk of code from the old `setup.py` file:

```
# We add all .cpp files to the sources 
sources = [ 'platec_src/platecmodule.cpp']
for f in os.listdir(cpp_src_dir):
  if f.endswith(".cpp"):
    sources.append("%s/%s" % (cpp_src_dir, f))
```

Specifically, the last line, which needed to be changed to:

```
# We add all .cpp files to the sources 
sources = [ 'platec_src/platecmodule.cpp']
for f in os.listdir(cpp_src_dir):
  if f.endswith(".cpp"):
    sources.append(os.path.join(cpp_src_dir, f))
```